# How to convert a datetime column to firstday of month?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, datetime-format

I have a PySpark dataframe with column which has datetime values in the format '09/19/2020 09:27:18 AM'
I want to convert to first day of month 01-Nov-2020 in this format.
I have tried `"date_col", F.trunc("date_col", "month")` which is resulting in `null` date
and

```
df_result = df_result.withColumn('gl_date', F.udf(lambda d: datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%MM/%dd/%yyyy %HH:%mm:%S a').strftime('%Y/%m/1'), t.StringType())(F.col('date_col')))
```

the second method I tried errors with date format '%MM/%dd/%yyyy %HH:%mm:%S a' is not matched with '09/19/2020 09:27:18 AM'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the column to timestamp type before calling `trunc`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_result2 = df_result.withColumn(
    'gl_date',
    F.date_format(
        F.trunc(
            F.to_timestamp("date_col", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"),
            "month"
        ),
        "dd-MMM-yyyy"   
    )
)
```

Comment: it works, but results in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format( 2020-09-01), I have to convert into 01-Nov-2020 format

Comment: +-------+
|gl_date|
|   null|  this it the output: (sorry I cant post the whole dataframe), and yes I have saved it again to the origianl dataframe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227182/discussion-between-mck-and-ravali-r).